# Lambert Function

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

I was using the Lambert function on python but I was not getting the correct results.
My actual code is

```
E = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = []
for f in E:
   W = scipy.special.lambertw((f-1)/np.exp(1), k=0, tol=1e-10)
   y.append(W)
```

In the above code, theoretically, the values should lie between -1 and 0. But that seems to be not the case here.

I noticed that, in the case of the principal branch, there is a slight discrepancy in the results. Wo(-1/e) = -1 but when I used the following code in python the answer was wrong.

```
scipy.special.lambertw(-1/np.exp(1), k=0, tol=1e-8)
>>> (nan+nanj)
```

Can someone help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: It seems to me like it is an issue when close to `-1/np.exp(1)`. It seems to work for `-1/np.exp(1)+1e-16`. There even [is a comment](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/701ffcc8a6f04509d115aac5e5681c538b5265a2/scipy/special/_lambertw.pxd#L19) in scipys source code about results when close to the branching point.

Comment: What *is* the expected result? That, and a [mcve], is missing from your question!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt,  thank you so much for your comment. I made an edit and I hope it works.

Comment: @FlyingTeller, you are right but for my code (I have made an edit), the results are not coming correctly.

Comment: What is providing `W`?

Comment: @chepner, W is the Lambert function.

Comment: Yes, but defined how? Did you define it? Is it imported from some other library?

Comment: @chepner, I just did. So sorry..it somehow slipped off my mind.

Comment: *"In the above code, theoretically, the values should lie between -1 and 0.  But that seems to be not the case here."*  Other than the first point (which is `nan+nanj`), the values in `y` *are* between -1 and 0.  Note that the values are complex, but the imaginary part is 0.  (I used SciPy version 1.6.2 to run the calculation.)

Comment: If you want a "second opinion", the [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/) package also has an implementation of [Lambert W](https://mpmath.org/doc/1.2.0/functions/powers.html#lambert-w-function).